# Empty struct after calling a function to populate it

Tags: c

I have a struct

```
typedef struct
{
  my ints
  and char's
} structname;
```

in my server `.c` file inside `main()`

```
structname Header;
```

I'm calling the `function(Header);`

which looks at another `.c` file

And populates the header with e.g. `strcpy(Header.Name1,pch);`

Which gets populated correctly as i have used `gdb` to debug it

```
(gdb) p Header.Name1
$5 = "Bilka\000\332\326\377\177\000\000\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\b]\022\"E\177\000\000p\356\332\326\377\177\000\000\034\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\t\000\000\000\000"
```

After this function ends and returns `TRUE` it goes back to the next line on the server.c but if i do a print on Header.Name1 i'm getting a blank header what could be the reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Function arguments in C are passed by value. So if your function's signature looks like this:

```
foo function(structname Header);
```

It means that the argument is *copied* when the function is called. You then modify that temporary copy inside the function, but that doesn't change the original object. You might want to pass a pointer to your struct to the function instead:

```
foo function(structname * Header)
{
  //...
  strcpy(Header->Name1, pch);
}

// ...
structname Header;
function(&Header);
printf("%s\n", Header.Name1);
```

Comment: `(gdb) p Header->Name1

Cannot access memory at address 0x6b6c69420000303d`

Getting this now after the function when i try print it

Comment: @greenarrow: That problem is not on my side. If you declare the struct like this and pass a pointer to it to the function right away, it should be available.

Comment: Wait, why `Header->Name1` *after* the function? You have to refer to it by `Header.Name1` if the struct is in the current scope.

Comment: request for member âName1â in something not a structure or union , the struct is declared in a declarations.h but am getting an error with .Name1

Comment: @greenarrow: Sorry, the error is somewhere else, not in this piece of code. BTW, why are you declaring global variables in a header file? That doesn't make any sense. If you need help with this, please provide a *minimal* failing example that you can't figure out.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10883/discussion-between-greenarrow-and-niklas-b)

Answer (score 1):

C functions are pass-by-value, so when you call `function(Header);`, you are passing **a copy** of the struct and modify it, you should pass a pointer to the struct to the other function:

```
function(&Header);
```